# Why do digital movies show aliasing and red/green chromatic aberration?

Tags: the-hobbit, film-industry

I just saw the second Hobbit film and some issues that I thought were present in the first Hobbit film really came through. The first issue was that nearly all hard diagonal lines, such as those on letters and designs, were heavily aliased. It was almost as if I was watching an old video game or VGA display. This issue wasn't very noticeable except during the titles and credits.

The other issue was that vertical lines showed a red "halo" on one side and a green one on the other. This was noticeable throughout the film and especially prominent on architecture.

Are these "features" of digital film, or the special high frame rate at which The Hobbit was filmed?

Comment: It sounds to me like the equipment it was shown on was at issue rather than the film itself. I didn't see any of these problems where I saw the film, though I admit I wasn't specifically looking for it. Something like this would have stuck out to me usually, so do not believe it was present. I saw the film in 3d High Frame Rate and it looked awesome in all aspects. I guess we'll wait for others to chime in.

Comment: @Reed G. Law, were you watching the film in 3D? you don't specify in your question, and it would be helpful in determining the origin of the issues you are discussing...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional no it was not 3D.

Comment: You should probably describe where you watched it and whether the location used a digital or film projector (and, if you can find out, what projection format was used). These facts might help.

Comment: Obviously this is not normal in digital projection in general or The Hobbit/HFR in specific. You should ask the cinema for a refund. Not for the money (alone) but to force them to fix their stuff.

Comment: This is the theater: http://www.carmike.com/ShowTimes/Theater/110

Comment: I believe it to be the fault of the projectionist. I also saw bad visual defects when I watched the first Hobbit in HFR 3D at the South Point cinema in Durham NC. During that showing there were quite bad horizontal convergence issues (what you describe as a halo effect). I complained a few times during the show but they said that the manager couldn't notice it and that they recalibrate the projectors daily...

Comment: An actual cinema had that issue? I am currently having that issue myself on my Westinghouse LED TV when I stream video: Anything red on a dark background will appear heavily aliased. So oddly enough, a video played on VLC did not have the problem, but I was able to recreate it to a small degree in Photoshop. This problem did not exist when I was using a standard computer monitor, but upon moving to this screen and also using HDMI [which this TV is wont to treat as not coming from a PC so it has all of these unnecessary sharpness/vibrance/what-have-you settings to deal with] so I'd say their pr

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is unreproducible and apparently local/one-off only.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware issue, not a question about the movie